# How to I specify a NuGet package comes from an external source in packages.config?

Tags: nuget

I am working on a project that has a dependency on a NuGet project that is on an external source. We are using package restore and not committing packages into Git. For developers that do not have this source configured in their NuGet settings, is there a way to specify in the packages.config file that this package should be pulled from a different source?

e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  ...

  <!-- How do I specify that this custom package comes from a different source? -->
  <package id="MyCustomPackage" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />

  ...
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I was hoping something along the lines of <package id="MyCustomPackage" source="http://www.mysource.com/nuget" /> but I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Comment: Same. The accepted answer is less than ideal. I'm doing triage on a build with 4 different nuget sources and nuget tries to grab each package from each source. It takes forever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each user can have their own config file, where you can specify the location of the sources:

```
<packageSources>
        <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="TestSource" value="C:\Temp" />
</packageSources>
```

For more info, see [docs here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file)

You can also configure this at the project or solution level by adding a NuGet.config to the project or solution.

Comment: Is there any way to set this up on a project level, so 0 manual steps required if a developer clones an existing source?

Comment: @KenSykora - If you take a look at the doc that Donal linked to you will see that you can add a NuGet.config to the project or solution. So if you check that into source control you can automagically have the custom package sources available for anybody who uses that project.

Comment: Awesome -- this needs to get way more visibility to new users through Visual Studio, akin to ReSharper "Save Team Settings". Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. It causes nuget to check all sources in the `NuGet.config` used *per-package*. For projects with many nuget packages and their dependencies this can cause quite a hiccup, especially in dynamic cloud-based build environments that don't heavily leverage cache.