# One person developer; need consolidated nuget of offline dev

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I make several projects offline and need to save space and consolidate all my downloaded nuget packages

How can VS use the same nuget packages folder of which to take copies from? I can’t get them while flying for example

Comment: Please have a look here: [Move packages folder inside the solution folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506438/move-packages-folder-inside-the-solution-folder)

Comment: for SDK style projects that use the new csproj format, NuGet packages are cosolidated offline in your .nuget folder under your user directory, so potentially you could update your projects to the newer csproj format?

Comment: Do you want to get a nuget package from specified source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24124335/14324452